# Pause video playback with JQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a video on my website and a button which should exchange the shown video with another one. When i do this, it works, but nevertheless the first video which was shown plays in the background after the change (i can here the sound of it). I want to pause the first video/stop playing it before it gets replaced, but this doesn't work. The code gets replaced perfectly but why is the first video still playing in the background? Any hints? Thanks!

```
<video id="video" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
<source src="inc/1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="inc/1.webm" type="video/webm">               
</video>
<div class="video-active" movie="one">Active Video</div>


$(function() {
    $(".section-video-button").on("click", function() {
        document.getElementById('video').pause();
        if ($('.video-active').attr('movie') == 'one') {
            $('#video').replaceWith('<video id="video" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"><source src="inc/2.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="inc/2.webm" type="video/webm"></video>');
            $('.video-active').attr('movie','two');
        } else {
            $('#video').replaceWith('<video id="video" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"><source src="inc/1.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="inc/1.webm" type="video/webm"></video>');
            $('.video-active').attr('movie','one');
        }

        $('#video').load();
    });
 });
```

Comment: Why don't you just change the video's `src` instead of what you have here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update jQuery page to include javascript/jQuery code to play and pause video.

```
$("video").trigger("play");
$("video").trigger("pause");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use .html() instead of using replaceWith(), or just change SRC attribute, insted of inserting whole code.

Also you can try to use .stop() function.